# How to combine onchange in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to combine this javascript because I have problem when selecting the grade-11 and grade-12 the work did not work but only the BSCS pick by user thank you for help

```
document.getElementById('course').onchange = function() {


if (["BSCS", "BSIT","BSHRM","BSBM","BSTM"].indexOf(this.value) > -1) {
    document.getElementById("grade-11").setAttribute("disabled", true);
    document.getElementById("grade-12").setAttribute("disabled", true);


 } 
 else {
    document.getElementById("grade-11").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("grade-12").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}




document.getElementById('course').onchange = function() {


 if (["STEM", "TOP","GAS","HUMSS"].indexOf(this.value) > -1) {
    document.getElementById("first-year").setAttribute("disabled", true);


    document.getElementById("second-year").setAttribute("disabled", true);
    document.getElementById("third-year").setAttribute("disabled", true);
    document.getElementById("fourth-year").setAttribute("disabled", true);
  } else {



document.getElementById("first-year").removeAttribute("disabled");


    document.getElementById("second-year").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("third-year").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("fourth-year").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, you set `document.getElementById('course').onchange` to be one thing then you set it to something else, overwriting the first.  You could use `element.addEventListener` to add multiple event listeners, or you could combine the code in the two onchange functions into one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (based on your logic) :

```
document.getElementById('course').onchange = function() {

if (["BSCS", "BSIT","BSHRM","BSBM","BSTM"].indexOf(this.value) > -1) {
    document.getElementById("grade-11").setAttribute("disabled", true);
    document.getElementById("grade-12").setAttribute("disabled", true);
    document.getElementById("first-year").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("second-year").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("third-year").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("fourth-year").removeAttribute("disabled");

 } else if (["STEM", "TOP","GAS","HUMSS"].indexOf(this.value) > -1) {

    document.getElementById("first-year").setAttribute("disabled", true);
    document.getElementById("second-year").setAttribute("disabled", true);
    document.getElementById("third-year").setAttribute("disabled", true);
    document.getElementById("fourth-year").setAttribute("disabled", true);
    document.getElementById("grade-11").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("grade-12").removeAttribute("disabled");

  } else {

    document.getElementById("grade-11").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("grade-12").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("first-year").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("second-year").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("third-year").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById("fourth-year").removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work they all disabled when I pick BS and TOP

Comment: If you pick TOP, only first to fourth will be disabled, and there is no BS, however, if you meant something from the first list then only the grades 11 and 12 will be disabled.

Comment: I mean if I pick any of BS, BSIT BSHRM etc.. , and when I pick gas etc.. they all will disable https://imgur.com/a/MNbhf

Comment: glad to help :)